# Como utilizar el texto almacenado en una variable como identificador de otra variable

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Existe alguna funcion que pueda utilizar para decirle al programa que el texto dentro de una variable es una referencia a un objeto al que quiero instanciar para que el busque ese objeto usando ese texto como identificador del mismo

El lenguaje que estoy utilizando es C# (con windows form VS)

Answer (score 1):

Con `Type.GetType(string typeName)` y `Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)` puedes lograrlo:

```
string className = "MiProyecto.Modelos.Persona";
Type classType = Type.GetType(className);
Persona persona = (Persona)Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
persona.Nombre = "Einer";
```

**Aqui un paso a paso.**

Primero guardamos el nombre de la clase completo con todo y namespace:

```
namespace MiProyecto.Modelos
{
  public class Persona
  {
     public int Id { get; set;}
     public string Nombre { get; set;}
  }
}
```

Entonces en la variable tendriamos:

```
string className = "MiProyecto.Modelos.Persona";
```

Ahora necesitamos el `System.Type` de la clase para poder inicializarla y lo obtenemos con `Type.GetType()`:

```
Type classType = Type.GetType(className);
```

Como ya tenemos la informacion de la clase, podemos inicializarla con `Activator.CreateInstance()`:

```
Persona persona = (Persona)Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
persona.Nombre = "Einer";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Buen día**

Esperando haber comprendido tu planteamento te comentoque he usado [**CreateIntance** de la clase *Activator*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx) para instanciar objetos sabiendo el tipo de dato; por lo cual considero para tu caso que deberás tambien apoyarte de **Type** para del string [obtener el tipo de dato con **GetType**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108786/typeof-how-to-get-type-from-string).

Como tal **CreateInstance** de *Activator* posee métodos que te permiten directamente crear desde strings pero requieres dos cadenas; este no los he usado; pero si [el que recibe como parámetro **Type**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx), ten en consideración que para usarlo, deberá tu clase tener un constructor sin parámetros.

*Saludos.*